# RecyclerView swiping to delete in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, swipe, itemtouchhelper

I'm trying to create a feature where if the user swipes LEFT on an item in the RecyclerView, the item will be deleted.

My RecyclerView is inside a Fragment which is inside a FrameLayout controlled by a BottomNavigation.

I have the code where it works when the RecyclerView is in its own Activity but when I transfer it into a Fragment, the swiping functionality breaks. I'm unable to swipe at all.

In my Fragment, I'm extending the `RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener` interface.

```
interface RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener {
    void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position);
}
```

Then I create a Callback

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback ItemTouchHelperCallbackLeft = new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, this);
new ItemTouchHelper(ItemTouchHelperCallbackLeft).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Now I create a function called `OnSwiped` to handle the swiping.

```
@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position) {
    if (viewHolder instanceof ListAdapter.ViewHolder) {
        if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            String cityName = stationList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getData().getCity();

            //Create a backup of the deleted item in case user wants to undo delete
            Station deletedStation = stationList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            int deletedStationIndex = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

            //Remove the item from RecyclerView
            listAdapter.removeItem(deletedStationIndex);

            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, cityName + " removed from list!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    // undo is selected, restore the deleted item
                    listAdapter.restoreItem(deletedStation, position);
                }
            });
            snackbar.show();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `RecyclerItemTouchHelper` class.

```
public class RecyclerItemTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
    private RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener;

    public RecyclerItemTouchHelper(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs, RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener) {
        super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        listener.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        if (viewHolder != null) {
            final View foregroundView = ((ListAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).listViewForeground;
            getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(foregroundView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDrawOver(Canvas canvas, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        final View foregroundView = ((ListAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).listViewForeground;
        getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(canvas, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        final View foregroundView = ((ListAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).listViewForeground;
        getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foregroundView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas canvas, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        final View foregroundView = ((ListAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).listViewForeground;

        getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(canvas, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    @Override
    public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
        return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that everything works when the RecyclerView is inside its own Activity, but when I transfer my RecyclerView into a Fragment this swiping function does not work.

Comment: I should clarify that my RecyclerView is inside a Fragment which is inside a FrameLayout controlled by a BottomNavigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed my issue by moving the Callback after I initialize my RecyclerView.

```
recyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback ItemTouchHelperCallbackLeft = new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, this);
new ItemTouchHelper(ItemTouchHelperCallbackLeft).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```